# (Oracle DSEE) LDAP browsing index with parameters in the vlvFilter

Tags: oracle, ldap

I'm running into some problems creating a browsing index for VLV searches.

The oracle docs (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19693-01/819-0995/bcatq/index.html) state that

```
The vlvFilter is the same LDAP filter that is used in the client search operations.
```

The filter I am using for the VLV searches however is parameterised, e.g.

```
(&(objectclass=MySpecialObjectClass)(modificationTimestamp>=$someDynamicValue))
```

So any ideas what should be put in the vlvFilter attribute for this browsing index?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use VLVIndex for filters that are constantly changing. VLVIndex are meant to provide consistent scrolling lists of results.
VLV must also come with a Sorting order.
It looks like to me that you may just need to index the modifyTimeStamp (for ordering) and use the Page Result Control to avoid getting all entries at once.

Comment: Sadly, the ODSEE doesn't support the simple paged control :/